# how to solve Passing DateTime value to paramaterized query Error

Tags: sql, datetime, datetimepicker, sql-convert

here is my query string

`SELECT

            Payment

            ,Balance

            ,PatientNo

            FROM

            [GP_DB].[dbo].[GP]

            where GP.GPDate= (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),@GPDate,103))`

GPDate is a Date type column, not DateTime

and i pass parameter like this

```
cmd_select_treatment.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@GPDate"
            ,Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value));
```

but the following error occur

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: the standard way to approach this is view the TSQL on the wire....

Comment: what sql you are using?? And are you using asp.net???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@var is DateTime
select cast(convert (varchar(8),@var,112) as Date)

Answer (score 2):

> GPDate is a Date type column

If it's a `DATE` column and your `Convert.ToDateTime` call returns a `DateTime` object then don't bother yourself with the `CAST`.

```
WHERE GP.GPDate = @GPDate
```

If `dateTimePicker1` might contain a time component and you don't care for that then simply discard it before using its value:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value).Date
```

Answer (score -1):

I Think you need to add picture clause in your date conversion like the example

```
to_date('18/01/2014 10:15:20','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

this should solve your problem